# best keyword searching technique

Tags: php, mysql, keyword

I have a table containing a column named title.

Input is taken from the user in form of string. The string is actually a group of keywords delimited by space.

I want to search the entire table looking for records with their title fields  containing some of the keywords as present in the string input by the user and the results need to be displayed in order of match.

For Ex:

```
RecordA -> title -> "apple mango grapes banana"
RecordB -> title -> "apple lemon orange"
RecordC -> title -> "banana"
RecordD -> title -> "lemon mango grapes"
```

Suppose the string input from the user is : "apple mango orange"
Then I want the result from the php page in order

```
Record A  // 2 matches
Record B  // 2 matches
Record D  // 1 match
Record C  // 0 match
```

Suggest me an efficient way to do this in php..

Note:  Database is in Mysql. It cannot be modified to add fulltext search index to the table.

Comment: This may be slow using a DB, since you will have to request all the table, and parse it yourself in PHP. If you are about to use large amount of data, you should use SolR, which is designed to do this kind of stuff...

Comment: It depends on your dataset, what is the size of your data ? 10, 100, 1 000, 10 000, 1 000 000 rows... ? and on words, how many words by rows ? 1-5, 1-20... ?

Comment: It is over 10 lakh rows presently and expanding..

Comment: Sorry.. 1000000 (10 lakh )

Comment: 10 lakh rows is kinda small and my guess is you won't want to integrate with other systems so plod thru it slow

Comment: Yeah, so don't even try to parse 1 000 000 rows in php, it would take many many many minutes... Have you ever heard about Solr ? We may continue in a chat : [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83134/best-keyword-searching-technique)

Comment: Given the opportunity to use `solr` I would jump on that. Mysql fulltext can be a frustrating journey time well spent elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is full text search (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)).  This *is* the right way to do what you want, and it is the most efficient by far.

What you can do in the absence of full text search is something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where title like '%word1%' or
      title like '%word2%' or
      . . .
order by ((title like '%word1%') +
          (title like '%word2%') +
          . . .
         ) desc;
```

You will have to parse the words the user provides to get each word.  Also note that you have a problem with word boundaries.  As phrased above this will find any occurrence of the string of letters, even if within a word.  If that is an issue, then use regular expressions instead of `like`.  But, the real solution is full text search.

Comment: What about perfs on 1 000 000 rows ?

Comment: What is that + sign for ??

Comment: @user2653926 he computes your score, to see how many matched words is in the actual row

Comment: @Random . . . It will require a full table scan.  I thought the answer was pretty clear that full text search is the way to go.

Comment: It is a way to go, yes, but as far as I know, using `LIKE` on a DB is time-greedy, so multiple `LIKE` may need much time. I've never used such fulltext search, so I wonder how much time it would take on 1 000 000 rows... 10sec, 2 mins, 30 mins... ?